# how to filter out sub-dictionary from a list of dictionary based on date range

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to filter out sub-dictionary from a list of dictionary based on date range

here is my list:

```
[{'5-jan-2019': '34'}, {'10-jan-2019': '34'}, {'21-jan-2019': '12'}, {'25-jan-2019': '34'} , {'5-feb-2019': '34'}]
```

I need to filter out all sub-dictionary within a range of date like

```
from_date-'5-jan-2019' and  to_date-'25-jan-2019'
```

and add it to new dictionary

expected result

```
{
    '5-jan-2019': '34',
    '10-jan-2019': '34',
    '21-jan-2019': '12',
    '25-jan-2019': '34'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want datetime.strptime to convert the strings to datetime objects, which you can then compare against each other.

```
from datetime import datetime

lst = [
    {'5-jan-2019': '34'},
    {'10-jan-2019': '34'},
    {'21-jan-2019': '12'},
    {'25-jan-2019': '34'},
    {'5-feb-2019': '34'},
    ]

dt_from_str = lambda dt: datetime.strptime(dt, '%d-%b-%Y')

start_date = dt_from_str('5-jan-2019')
end_date = dt_from_str('25-jan-2019')

new_dict = {}
for sub_dict in lst:
    for key, val in sub_dict.items():
        if start_date <= dt_from_str(key) <= end_date:
            new_dict[key] = val

print(new_dict)
```

output:

```
{
    '5-jan-2019': '34',
    '10-jan-2019': '34',
    '21-jan-2019': '12',
    '25-jan-2019': '34',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `datetime` module to utilize the built-in comparison methods (`__lt__`, etc) of the `datatime.datetime` object:

```
import datetime
data = [{'5-jan-2019': '34'}, {'10-jan-2019': '34'}, {'21-jan-2019': '12'}, {'25-jan-2019': '34'} , {'5-feb-2019': '34'}]
start, end = '5-jan-2019', '25-jan-2019'
```

---

```
def d_form(d):
   months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']
   _d, _m, _y = d.split('-')
   return datetime.datetime(int(_y), months.index(_m)+1, int(_d))

start, end = d_form(start), d_form(end)
final_result = [i for i in data if start <= d_form(list(i.keys())[0]) <= end]
```

Output:

```
[{'5-jan-2019': '34'}, 
 {'10-jan-2019': '34'}, 
 {'21-jan-2019': '12'}, 
 {'25-jan-2019': '34'}]
```